# Classic ADO.NET - How to Pass UDT To Stored Procedure?

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, ado.net, user-defined-types

**I have this SQL Server 2008 UDT:**

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IdentityType] AS TABLE(
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

Pretty simple. Basically allows me to hold onto a list of id's.

**I have this stored procedure:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Scoring_ScoreMultipleLocations]
    @LocationIds [IdentityType] READONLY,
    @DoRanking BIT = 0
AS
BEGIN
   -- irrelevant code.
END
```

Entity Framework 4.0 does not support executing stored procedures that take user defined table types as a parameter, so i'm reverting to classic ADO.NET. The only other option is passing a comma-seperated string.

Anyway, i found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sqlserver2008.aspx) article, but it's a little hard to follow.

I don't understand what this line of code is doing:

> DataTable dt = preparedatatable();

They don't even provide that method, so i have no idea what i'm supposed to do here.

This is my method signature:

```
internal static void ScoreLocations(List<int> locationIds, bool doRanking)
{
   // how do i create DataTable??
}
```

So i have a list of `int` and need to pump that into the UDT.

Can anyone help me out/point me to a clear article on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) might be a bit more help.

Essentially, you'll create a new DataTable that matches the schema, then pass it as a parameter.

The code of preparedatatable() probably would look something like:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
return dt;
```

After which, you'd have to add your locationIds:

```
foreach(var id in locationIds)
{
    var row = dt.NewRow();
    row["Id"] = id;
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Then assign dt as a parameter:

```
var param = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocationIDs", dt);
param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
param.TypeName = "dbo.IdentityType";
```

Comment: Ahh k, that makes sense. Trying out now, stay tuned... (+1 for now).

Comment: works, *but* - for some reason it's taking over 10 seconds, then finally sql profiler shows "Error - 2 - Aborted". The sql produced looks fine - when i run it in ssms it takes < sec. So i'm now trying this approach instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837350/table-valued-parameter-in-stored-procedure-and-the-entity-framework-4-0 Thanks anyway

Comment: I have used this without it taking 10 seconds; Not sure what would cause that.  Anyway, if the parameter only needs to be a list of integers, you are probably better off with a CSV list and a split function anyway.  TVPs really help out when you are trying to send in multiple associated values for each row (eg, multiple columns in your type) where with a CSV list this would require a secondary delimiter (eg, a CSV list of pipe delimited data).