# Sql server 2008 user defined data types

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-types

Can anybody please tell me what user defined data type is in sql server and also how to create one.

And can i create a user defined datatype which resembles a .net datatable and pass this datatable as parameter to a stored procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this introductory article here: ["What's the Point of [SQL Server] User-Defined Types?"](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/archive/2005/10/07/426930.aspx)

This answer on SO explains how to pass these UDT types to a stored procedure: [Classic ADO.NET - How to Pass UDT To Stored Procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719507/classic-ado-net-how-to-pass-udt-to-stored-procedure)