# EntityFrameWork and TableValued Parameter

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, bulkinsert, table-valued-parameters

I'm trying to call a stored procedure from **EntityFramework** which uses **Table-value** parameter.

But when I try to do function import I keep getting a warning message saying -

> The function 'InsertPerson' has a parameter 'InsertPerson_TVP' at
>   parameter index 0 that has a data type 'table type' which is currently
>   not supported for the target .NET Framework version. The function was
>   excluded.

I did a initial search here and found few posts which says It's possible in EntityFrameWork with some work arounds and [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837350/table-valued-parameter-in-stored-procedure-and-the-entity-framework-4-0) saying it's not supported in current versions.

Does any one know a better approach or solution for this problem?

Comment: EF doesn't support TVP. If you found a workaround just try it or don't use EF to call stored procedure with TVP.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I ended up doing this, Please note we are working on EF `DataContext`(not `ObjectContext`)

**Executing a Stored procedure with output parameter**

```
       using (DataContext context = new DataContext())
        {                  
          ////Create table value parameter
          DataTable dt = new DataTable();
          dt.Columns.Add("Displayname");
          dt.Columns.Add("FirstName");
          dt.Columns.Add("LastName");
          dt.Columns.Add("TimeStamp");

          DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
          dr["Displayname"] = "DisplayName";
          dr["FirstName"] = "FirstName";
          dr["LastName"] ="LastName";
          dr["TimeStamp"] = "TimeStamp";             
          dt.Rows.Add(dr);

          ////Use DbType.Structured for TVP
          var userdetails = new SqlParameter("UserDetails", SqlDbType.Structured);
          userdetails.Value = dt;
          userdetails.TypeName = "UserType";

          ////Parameter for SP output
          var result = new SqlParameter("ResultList", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 4000);
          result.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

          context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC UserImport @UserDetails, @ResultList OUTPUT", userdetails, result);

          return result == null ? string.Empty : result.Value.ToString();
        }
```

My **Table-Value-Parameter** (UDT Table) script looks like this:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[UserType] AS TABLE (
    [DisplayName]      NVARCHAR (256)   NULL,
    [FirstName]        NVARCHAR (256)   NULL,
    [LastName]         NVARCHAR (256)   NULL,
    [TimeStamp]        DATETIME         NULL
   )
```

And my **store procedure** begins like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UserImport 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@UserDetails UserType Readonly,
@ResultList NVARCHAR(MAX) output  
AS
```

For Stored procedure without `output` parameter we don't need any ouput parameter added/passed to SP.

Hope it helps some one.

Comment: Where is the instantiation of dr? I'm getting errors due to DataRowBuilder's protection level.

Comment: isnt your function a UDT (User Defined Type) and not a UDF (User Defined Function) ?

Comment: Yes, TVP is a User defined type.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps we could also consider the [SqlQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696545%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method:

```
[Invoke]
public SomeResultType GetResult(List<int> someIdList)
{
    var idTbl = new DataTable();
    idTbl.Columns.Add("Some_ID");

    someIdList.ForEach(id => idTbl.Rows.Add(id));

    var idParam = new SqlParamter("SomeParamName", SqlDbType.Structured);
    idParam.TypeName = "SomeTBVType";
    idParam.Value = idTbl;

    // Return type will be IEnumerable<T>
    var result = DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<SomeResultType>("EXEC SomeSPName, @SomeParamName", idParam);

    // We can enumerate the result...

    var enu = result.GetEnumerator();
    if (!enu.MoveNext()) return null;
    return enu.Current;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
            var detailTbl = new DataTable();
        detailTbl.Columns.Add("DetailID");
        detailTbl.Columns.Add("Qty");
        txnDetails.ForEach(detail => detailTbl.Rows.Add(detail.DetailID, detail.Qty));

        var userIdParam = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int);
        userIdParam.Value = 1;

        var detailParam = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Details", SqlDbType.Structured);
        detailParam.TypeName = "DetailUpdate";
        detailParam.Value = detailTbl;

        var txnTypeParam = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@TransactionType", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        txnTypeParam.Value = txnType;

        var result = await db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("MySP @UserID, @Details, @TransactionType", userIdParam, detailParam, txnTypeParam);
        if(result >= 0)
            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        else
            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
```